# What does it cost to query files/data in different GCS storage classes from BigQuery (federated/external query)?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have 2 GCS buckets with identical, sharded CSV files. Bucket *federated-query-standard* has storage class of `standard`. Bucket *federated-query-archive* has storage class of `archive`.

Running identical queries using federated/external source over the buckets produce to exact same amount of bytes billed/processed, which is 57.13GB of data. Performance (query time) is roughly the same.

According to the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#gcs_pricing) for BigQuery pricing:

> *"When querying an external data source from BigQuery, you are charged
> for the number of bytes read by the query. For more information, see
> Query pricing. You are also charged for storing the data on Cloud
> Storage. For more information, see Cloud Storage Pricing."*

So, users are charged on **two** things: the data processed and the storage of the data in GCS. This makes complete sense.

**My question**: is there is a hidden cost anywhere that I'm not seeing (or unaware of) for querying GCS (e.g. retrieval costs) or between different storage classes?

Comment: Is that documented somewhere Mikhail? Also, looking at the bucket information after I perform the query on it, it still shows "archive" as its class.

Comment: no. didn't see any explicit info on this. that was my guess (that is why I put it as a comment). sounds as a wild guess though when I am reading it now

Comment: No problem. I know archive data is more expensive to retrieve when going directly through the GCS API, but it's not clear if these costs are passed onto users when accessing from BigQuery. I also don't see any evidence of this in my billing.

Comment: You should be charged for the read of the archive file class. But, the fact that you are seeing nothing in your billing part is strange (class A or B is very low, not a concern. But the archive class reading is expensive: $0.05 per GB, $3 in your case). It sounds more like a bug than a feature! Did you have tried with other storage class? Archive class being the most recent, it's maybe a mistake!!

Comment: Fair points Guillaume. I haven't tried with other storage classes. That's a good idea. I'll do that and report back.

Comment: I tested with Coldline. Still doesn't show up in billing.

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley I would recommend you to contact Google's 1:1 support directly for billing reasons, for free. Just access this link [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases?_ga=2.81165970.467416249.1592814515-387989268.1584431183&_gac=1.141369734.1592892980.EAIaIQobChMIo67X26SX6gIVxVQYCh1UVwSAEAAYASAAEgL_DPD_BwE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there aren't any charges for reading from Archival or Coldine storage, hidden or otherwise. That doesn't mean this won't change in the future.

Because of the way BigQuery accesses GCS, GCS charges BigQuery for the access, not you (i.e. an internal accounting thing).

Performance may be inconsistent if you use archival storage. For that storage class, there are fewer redundant copies so tail latency will be higher.

For coldline, however, you should see roughly equivalent performance to standard GCS storage. The reason is that under the covers, coldline is implemented exactly the same way as standard storage. The difference is that coldline charges less for storage but makes it up on reads.

Since BigQuery doesn't charge you for reads, if you're doing a lot of federated querying over data in GCS but don't read the data much otherwise, your best bet is going to be to use coldline.

Again, this is a point-in-time response and this may change in the future.